# Will my square pad short if the pour isolation is too small?

Tags: eaglecad, via, trace, copper-pour

How do I get the pour to isolate the pad and not the drill here? I'm assuming the square pad goes all the way through and will short my second layer (in teal). Am I correct?

[image: Square Pin vs Pour]

**update:** Confirmed! I put a pour on the top layer and it isolated the pad.

[image]

Comment: What software is that..?

Comment: This looks like eagle, why not make the pad circular?

Comment: Review that point on the Gerber files just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Sorry - It's eagle. The pad choice was arbitrary. I wanted a bigger pad since it's for a relay and will be moving high current (120v/20A), and I liked the square pad better than the big circle and octagon (wanted the extra surface for the solder). Not even sure if that's a good reason...

Comment: 20A, and that little dark blue bottom trace is all that connects to it? Guess you won't need to add any fuses then.

Comment: 120V and you're using the default clearances? Please find out the proper design guidelines for mains voltages in your area and follow them. In 240V land I try to maintain 7mm clearance between Live/Hot and anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This coil is 5V/100μA (G5RL-U1A-E-DC5) - that's what you're looking at. The switch carrying the mains is on a 4mm wide pour over all 4 layers, no thermals, isolated from the low voltage by a 4mm gap. Good catch, though. I should have been more specific. Still - probably a good idea to find some proper guidelines for dealing with mains voltage, which I have not done yet.

Comment: Looks like I'm safe @ 1mm, if I'm reading this correctly (0.6mm, to be exact). Smaller than expected... http://www.smpspowersupply.com/ipc2221pcbclearance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PCB layout software makes the isolation circular as it only needs to isolate for the hole. The pad will only be made on the top layer and bottom layer. 
The hole is probably plated, but it will not generate a metal square on the mid layers (teal), so there is no need for a square isolation. When you put a pour on the outer layers (top and bottom) it will isolate for the square shape.

Comment: Confirmed! I put a pour on the top layer and it isolated the pad. Thanks!

http://imgur.com/a/LAAEx

Comment: Indeed. In Eagle plated holes are always circular on inner layers, even if you select square/octagon/long/etc.